# How to tell if your Fortran program has been compiled with OpenMP or not?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm curious as to if there's a way to tell if your program has been compuled with `-fopenmp` or `-xopenmp` etc. and subsequently write something to the screen saying, "OpenMP being used etc..." or if it has been complied without `-fopenmp` or `-xopenmp` write "OpenMP not being used..."

Is there a flag that can be used to tell if the program has been compiled with OpenMP or compiled without so I could write something within my program like I've briefly written below?

```
program main 
  use omp_lib
  implicit none 

  !define other variables here...
  logical :: complied_with_openmp

  if(complied_with_openmp .eqv. .true.) write(6,*) 'OpenMP used...'
  if(complied_with_openmp .eqv. .false.) write(6,*) 'Openmp not used...'

  !some other code here...


end program
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. More people will see it. Fortran 90 is just one old and obsolete version (file .f90 does NOT mean Fortran 90!). Also, the exact Fortran standard is irrelevant for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What exactly does .f90 mean then? I was told it was for Fortran 90? Or would that be .F90?

Comment: Both .f90 and .F90 is for any free form Fortran (of any standard, like 90,95,2003,2008,2018...). With the capital letter in .F90 it goes through a pre-processing step first. Even modern Fortran can still be written in the fixed form and the the source file is typically .f or .for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is quite strange. Don't you actually want to ask if you are compiling with OpenMP right now? That can be done by using the `!$` syntax. Statements after `!$` are only compiled with OpenMP.

```
 logical :: compiled_with_openmp = .false.

  !$ compiled_with_openmp = .true.

  if (compiled_with_openmp) then
      write(*,*) 'OpenMP used...'
  else
      write(*,*) 'Openmp not used...'
  end if
```

Also, don't use unit 6, use `*`, it is more portable and nicer.

And do not compare logicals with .true. or .false., just do `if (condition)`, doing `if (condition .eqv. .true.)` is superficial or even confusing. And if the two conditions are actually opposite, just use `if  else` to join them.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a Fortran 2008 compliant compiler you can use the intrinsic function `compiler_options` to find out what compiler options were used; it's in the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.  I imagine that compilers which don't (yet) provide this may have non-standard ways of determining what compiler options were used.

You could then use `index` to figure out if the compiler options include the flag to engage OpenMP.  On my installation of gfortran the expression

```
index(compiler_options(),'openmp')
```

returns a non-0 value when the code is compiled with `-fopenmp`.

`omp_lib` provides the integer constant `openmp_version` to tell you what version you're using.  To be more accurate, it returns an integer `yyyymm` which decodes to the year and month of the release of the OpenMP version, rather than a direct representation of the version, such as `4.5`.